# I’m getting artifacts when setting up a cavity node shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine

There are white lines and dots I cannot explain where they come from. The mesh in the areas is flat, there is no non-manifold or loose geometry. The normal maps appear fine.

The normals are fine - all blue when I make face orientation visible. In fact, I can bake out a normal map and there is nothing abnormal visible in the affected areas.

Some areas are higher poly than others, because of dyntopo sculpting in some areas. If I bake it into a diffuse (cavity) map, it carries over to the low poly.

It’s in cycles and the effect works as expected and is visible. The problem is it creates also these artifacts which look like someone drew with a white Sharpie over the mesh. It is directly related to the color ramp node - I can change the color and intensity of the artifacts when changing the values of that node.

It affects several meshes and moving them to a new file with the default blender template doesn't fix the problem.

In the screenshots you can see one of the meshes in object mode, then edit mode (2 million verts), then a close up of the topology where a white line is drawn. Nothing unusual, no 2 overlapping faces or similar. In the mesh options, there is also no custom normals or anything as far as I can see.

[image: Object mode]

[image: Edit mode]

[image: close-up]

Answer (score 0):

The white artifacts are caused because the scale of your mesh is either too small or too big.

Scale the high poly (and the lowpoly if you wanna bake) up/down and apply the scale each time. If you hit the right scale the white lines should disappear.